# Unable to connect to pi 4 Ad-Hoc network

Tags: networking, pi-4, raspbian-buster, dhcp

I've been trying to create an ad hoc server using a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian GNU Linux 11 (Buster) following this [forum post](https://lcdev.dk/2012/11/18/raspberry-pi-tutorial-connect-to-wifi-or-create-an-encrypted-dhcp-enabled-ad-hoc-network-as-fallback/). I've modified it slightly to make it simpler, rather than any logical checks for existing networks etc. it launches directly into ad-hoc mode on boot.

What I've done:

1. Set up a DHCP Server

- Installed isc-dhcp-server using `sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server`
- Changed `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` to

```
# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
# Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="wlan0"
INTERFACESv6=""
```

- Changed `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to

```
DHCPDARGS=wlan0; #args for the dhcpd daemon -> limit DHCP to the wlan0 interface
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
 
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
option domain-name "RPi-network";
option routers 10.0.0.1; #default gateway
 
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.20; #IP range to offer
}
 
#static IP-assignment
host myLaptop {
    hardware ethernet 11:aa:22:bb:33:cc;
    fixed-address 10.0.0.100;
}
```

- Changed `/etc/network/interfaces` to

```
# start interfaces upon start of the system
auto lo wlan0
 
# register loopback interface
iface lo inet loopback
 
# use dhcp and allow interface to be started when kernel detects a hotplug event
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
 
# use manual ip configuration for wlan0 interface and allow hotplug as well
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

2. Setup rc.local to launch the interface as an ad hoc network on boot. My rc.locallooks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will “exit 0” on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ “$_IP” ]; then
printf “My IP address is %s\n” “$_IP”
fi

# RPi Network Conf Bootstrapper

createAdHocNetwork(){
echo “Creating ad-hoc network”
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 key aaaaa11111 #WEP key you can change this but keep it 10 digits
iwconfig wlan0 essid pi_Ad-Hoc #SSID set this to whatever you want
ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.200 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
/usr/sbin/dhcpd wlan0
echo “Ad-hoc network created”
echo “The server ip is 10.0.0.200”
}

createAdHocNetwork


exit 0
```

I can see this network from other devices, but when attempting to connect from a win10 laptop and a Google Pixel 4a both the connection reaches 'Secured' before giving the error 'Can't connect to this network'. On Windows, I can see a small circled x by the network name.
`journalctl | grep -i dhc` yields the following after attempted connection:

> Mar 04 16:41:27 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
> Mar 04 16:41:30 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
> Mar 04 16:41:33 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
> Mar 04 16:41:38 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
> Mar 04 16:41:52 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
> Mar 04 16:42:01 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
> Mar 04 16:42:09 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
> Mar 04 16:42:28 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
> Mar 04 16:42:28 raspberrypi dhclient[273]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
> Mar 04 16:42:51 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: failed to renew DHCP, rebinding
> Mar 04 16:42:51 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.2 from e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:42:51 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.2 to e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:42:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: reuse_lease: lease age 4 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.0.0.2
> Mar 04 16:42:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.2 from e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:42:55 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.2 to e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:04 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: reuse_lease: lease age 13 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.0.0.2
> Mar 04 16:43:04 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.2 from e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:04 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.2 to e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:19 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: reuse_lease: lease age 28 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.0.0.2
> Mar 04 16:43:19 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.2 from e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:19 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.2 to e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:52 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: reuse_lease: lease age 61 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.0.0.2
> Mar 04 16:43:52 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.2 from e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:52 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.2 to e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: DHCP lease expired
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: deleting route to 10.0.0.0/24
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: deleting default route via 10.0.0.1
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: reuse_lease: lease age 66 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.0.0.2
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPDISCOVER from e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPOFFER on 10.0.0.2 to e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: offered 10.0.0.2 from 10.0.0.200
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: reuse_lease: lease age 66 (secs) under 25% threshold, reply with unaltered, existing lease for 10.0.0.2
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.200) from e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpd[700]: DHCPACK on 10.0.0.2 to e4:5f:01:d4:81:c3 (raspberrypi) via wlan0
> Mar 04 16:43:57 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: probing address 10.0.0.2/24
> Mar 04 16:44:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: leased 10.0.0.2 for 534 seconds
> Mar 04 16:44:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: adding route to 10.0.0.0/24
> Mar 04 16:44:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[459]: wlan0: adding default route via 10.0.0.1

`jounralctl -u isc-dhcp-server` only shows the first run errors from not being configured. Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve or even just troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to be joking - trying to follow a 10+ year old tutorial for an obsolete OS. Virtually everything you have done is obsolete. You probably don't want an ad-hoc network anyway - just create an Access Point.

Comment: your question is not even about the Raspberry Pi ... it is a question about Linux

Comment: @Milliways I guess I was too stuck on the term ad-hoc as a large proportion of responses I found using it as a keyword were quite outdated (as you said lol), already finding much more promising and contemporary reading using Access Point. Thank you!